# Как сделать так, чтобы переменная, сгенерированная в directive, передалась в другой контроллер?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angular, angularjs-controller, angular-directive

У меня есть контроллер и директива к нему:

```
app.controller('BreedController', function ($scope, $http) {
$http.get('GetNonZeroBreeds')
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.breedsList = response.data
    })
});

app.directive('gallerybuttons', function () {
return {
    scope: true,
    replace: true,
    restrict: 'EAC',
    controller: 'BreedController',
    controller: 'CurGalleryTab',
    template: '\
        <div class= "ButtonBreads" >\
        <span ng-repeat="e in breedsList">\
        <button class="btn btn-default" id="{{ e }}" ng-click="CurGal.setGalTab(1, \'{{e}}\')"> {{ e }} </button>\
        </span>\
        </div>'
}
});
```

После выполнения, код, вставленный в html выглядит так:

[image: Код после вставки]

Дальше, событие ng-click у меня обрабатывается через другой контроллер, в который передаю параметры функции. Так выглядит второй контроллер:

```
app.controller('CurGalleryTab', function () {
this.gallerytab = 1;
this.buttonname = '';

this.setGalTab = function (newTab, newName) {
    this.gallerytab = newTab;
    this.buttonname = newName;
    console.log("GalleryTab is set to: " + this.gallerytab + " and button called " + this.buttonname);
};
});
```

Но он почему-то получает вторую переменную не как строку, а как объект {{e}} из директивы, вот так в итоге выглядит вывод результата работы второго контроллера:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но мне необходимо, чтобы в метод приходила именно строка 'chihuahua' например. Как это можно решить? Не понимаю

Comment: так как в ng-click идет код ангуляра - то `'{{}}'`  не нужны и вызов должен выглядеть так: `ng-click="CurGal.setGalTab(1, e)"`

Comment: Grundy, все, понял, да, сработала вставка просто как e. Спасибо!